# Installing Pika

Tags: python, python3

I have Python 2.7 and 3.5 installed in my Ubuntu.
I installed Pika.

Now I can import Pika only in Pyhton 2.7 and not in 3.5 .
How can I import Pika from Python 3.5

I have aliased python=python3.5

-Thanks,
JMH

Comment: How did you install it, wouldn't a virtualenv not be better?

Comment: Does installation of `python-pika` and/or `python3-pika` work for you?

Comment: The `python` command should point to python2 (python 2.7).  Pointing to python 3.x will break your system quite horribly. Essential system components (including the package manager) rely upon access to the correct version of python.

Comment: Initially installed Pika using the command below :
sudo -H pip install pika 
Which I was able to import only in Python 2.7
Later using :
sudo -H pip3 install pika
Now I am able to import Pika from python 3.5 

Regarding the virtualenv, I need to check. I do not know much about the 'virtualenv' concepts as of now.

Removed the alias for : python=python3.5.

My rephrased question :
[I think this is more generic]

How do I install any packages in Python that works for multiple versions in the system ?
[Like : same single installation of 'pika' works for both Python 2.7 and 3.5]

Answer (score 1):

JMH as you figured it out yourself:

**pip3** install *package*

installs the package for **python3** interpreter

*and*

**pip** install  *package*

installs the package for **python2** interpreter

As of yet, there is **no way to install simultaneously for both** interpreters using a single command. Hence use pip and pip3 accordingly.

Also it is **unwise to alter python aliases**. To invoke python3 interpreter use python3 command and for python2 just use python command.

Happy coding!